# Stuck with bricked OS

Tags: rooting, ota-update, samsung-galaxy-s-10

A few days ago I've updated my rooted(with magisk) galaxy s10(SM-G973F) to the latest firmware(patched with magisk) of ILO(`G973FXXU7CTF1` - my previous firmware - `G973FXXU4BTA8` - had one ui 2.0), and it seems that since then, it is pretty much bricked.

GBWhatsapp Mini doesn't work anymore(can't download media), Google Play tells me Netflix and a bunch of other apps are "not compatible with your device" and I can't connect my Galaxy Watch anymore(stuck on pairing).

I've previously tried to upgrade it to `G973FXXU4CTC9` and had the same issue so I've downgraded back to `G973FXXU4BTA8` and it was all fixed, but now it won't let me even downgrade(SW REV CHECK FAIL)..

What can I do then?

Thanks

Comment: you have upgraded bootloader from U4 -> U7

Comment: @alecxs correct. Is it related?

Comment: you can't downgrade bootloader so you can't downgrade ROM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually solved it...

The Galaxy Watch thing + the Netflix thing were solved with this combination(not sure which of these steps solved it):

1. Installed `MagiskHide Props Config` module and blocked the following using `Magisk Hide`:

   - Galaxy Watch Plugin(all)
   - Galaxy Wearable(all)
   - Google Play Games
   - Google Play Music
   - Google Play Services for AR
   - Google Services Framework
   - NFC
   - Samsung Health
   - Wearable Manager Installer
   - Google Play services(`com.google.android.gms` and `com.google.android.gms.unstable` only)
   - Google Play Store(all except `com.android.vending`)
2. Ran these commands as root:

```
mount -w -o remount /vendor
cp --preserve=all /vendor/etc/vintf/manifest.xml /vendor/etc/vintf/manifest.xml.bak
sed -i /`grep wsm /vendor/etc/vintf/manifest.xml|sed 's@/@\\\/@'|sed 's@>@\\>@g'|sed 's@<@\\<@g'|tr -d ' '`/,/'<hal format="hidl">'/d /vendor/etc/vintf/manifest.xml
mount -r -o remount /vendor
```

2. Installed `Bluetooth Library Patcher` module

Now the GBWhatsapp Mini problem. For some reason it required that `Install unknown apps` permission would be allowed for it.

Now everything works fine.